# how to run a game as server with multiple clients?

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, client-server

I wrote an adventure game in c and now I want to run that as a server(telnet) with multiple clients.I want each player to have the separate copy of the game.

I'm not really familiar with socket programming and dont know how can I do this or how to start and I read some tutorial but did not help . any help ?
notice that I've done all this programming in **ubuntu ** .

Comment: I suggest you start with doing a Google search for "linux socket tutorial", and continue from there.

Comment: actually I read several tutorial but dont understand how can I use my game code in that !

Comment: I think that you must at least tell us what kind of game is it. Is it a Graphic game? Or a text adventure?

Comment: that's a bit hard for us to help you on that one without the game code, don't you think?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is a single-player [MUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD). There are many different MUD engines available for download, maybe you can take a look at how they are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really really hard to answer without more details on what you define as an adventure game...

If your game was designed/implemented as single player on a console, just bolting on some socket code is not going to suddenly make it multi player.

You could write a daemon: when each player connects to it, it forks a new process then execs your game - the client is just to enter commands etc and the only changes to your game are to use sockets rather than console IO. But there is no real benefit to this compared to multiple people running different copies of your game.

What I'm guessing you really want is the server to contain some "shared info" e.g. how many players are playing, the location of each etc. To do this you need to figure out a set of messages that you expect to send back and forward from client to server. You need to figure out what parts of the code are client side and which are server.

Basically I think the actual socket code is easy, the design and architecture of your game and how it makes use of sockets is the harder part!

Comment: I think I should write a daemon as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets in C is really an intersting thing to work with.

First you have to come up with an adequate *protocol*, and you have to implement it inside your client manager.

To have multiple clients you have to have multiple sockets, one for each client, and one "main" socket to *listen* for connections.

The main socket is created through the use of `socket()`, and then you have to use `accept()` to listen for connections. Upon connection from a client to your socket, `accept()` will return a new socket, reserved for communication with this client.

Sockets act as files, thus socket items are used as file descriptors. To ensure you have a good loop you must use `select()` giving it all your sockets, to know when :

- You have a new connection pending on your main socket,
- You can write to a client,
- You have something to read from a client.

On how to implement your game with this, it highly depends on what's your game and how is it played.

I suggest you implement a queue of actions, buffered when a client do something, and resolve them as soon as you can. Use the timeout of `select()` to help you on this.

Comment: I want to run the program as server, Which I can connect to using, for instance, telnet. The server should  handle any number of simultaneously connected players.The diﬀerent plays should be separate from each other, each player is operating in his/her own copy of the world. I wrote the adventure game for a single player!